# Codeigniter Route url parents page and child page

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

Edit: I am new Codeigniter I am not how to use Codeigniter Routing. I create Contact Us page and Map page. Map page is the subpage of Contact Us page.

Table Name : Pages

```
id  label       link            parent
1   Contact Us  contact-us      0
3   About Us    about-us        0
2   Map         map             1
```

Here my Controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Page extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model('page_model');
    }
    public function index()
    {   

        $data['getAllPage'] = $this->page_model->getAllPages(); 

        $this->load->view('page_listing',$data);

    }
    public function view($id) {
        $data['single_page'] = $this->page_model->displaySinglePage($id);
        $this->load->view('single_page',$data);
    }
}
```

In routes.php I have put $route['(:any)'] = "page/view/$1";

When I enter url "http://mytest.dev/contact-us/" or "http://mytest.dev/about-us/" it show correct content of Contact page but I enter "http://mytest.dev/contact-us/map" it still show content of Contact page.

What I want when I enter "http://mytest.dev/contact-us/map" it shuold show content of Map page

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you are talking about setting up static pages in CI...if so, please post your controller logic that you setup for your static pages.

Comment: Dynamic Page not static page

Comment: Tell us controller name and its method names. From that it would be easy to configure routes.

Comment: I have Add Controller code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try code maybe can help

```
// Parents and Child page.
$route['page/(:any)/(:num)'] = "page/view/$1/$2";

// For Main Home Page.
$route['(:any)'] = "page/view/$1";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think following routes should work

```
$route['contact-us'] = 'page/view/$1';

$route['contact-us/map'] = 'page/view/$2';
```

when you'll echo $id in view method.

"http://mytest.dev/contact-us/" will print $1

and

"http://mytest.dev/contact-us/map" will print $2

Hope this solution will help.

Comment: Thanks for reply. your anwser is static url what I want url is dynamic. Sorry tell you not clearly

Comment: So, how many URLs you want to point to view method? Is it only contact-us and about-us? Or there are more?

Answer (score 1):

My site has a main 'events' page and an 'events/calendar' page. Create the pages as separate views and then create a function for each sub page in the main controller. Here's my Events controller. If you want a dynamic page you can add the appropriate code in the function.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Events extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('inc/header.php');
        $this->load->view('events_view');
        $this->load->view('inc/footer.php');
    }

    public function calendar()
    {
        $this->load->view('inc/header.php');
        $this->load->view('calendar_view');
        $this->load->view('inc/footer.php');
    }
}
```